# JavaFX TimeAxis (In realtime Chart)

Tags: java, javafx, charts, real-time

I need to build the LineChart in JavaFX which has the axis X with time values (chart is updated fastly in real time). I take the example from Essembly (realtime chart) and try to make time labels in X Axis, but no results becouse values define not in right way... I have searched much but no sucessfull results. Help please to find linechart with timeAxis. The realisation - only JavaFX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638173/how-can-i-make-a-dynamic-line-chart-with-javafx-using-a-socket-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing to do some time ago.
I don't remember everything and I don't have the time to think about it right now but I hope this will help you.

```
public void createChart(){
        series.getData().clear();
        int l=(int)Math.round(this.position-(this.tailleSerie/this.zoom));


        for(int i=l;i<this.position;i++){
            this.calendar.setTimeInMillis((time-((this.tailleSerie-1)-i))*60000);

            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(String.valueOf(this.myFormatter.format(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)))+":"+String.valueOf(myFormatter.format(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE))), data.get(this.time-((this.tailleSerie-1)-i))));

        }


        ((ValueAxis<Number>) this.graph.getYAxis()).setLowerBound(min-(5*(max-min))/100);
        ((ValueAxis<Number>) this.graph.getYAxis()).setUpperBound(max+(5*(max-min))/100);

        this.graph.getData().clear();
        this.graph.getData().add(series);




}
```

I just recreate the chart every few seconds with a "Platform.runLater(() ->createChart());".

I hope this will help you.

Comment: you don't need everything there but I have to go and didn't had time to select .